# Should initial filters for a 1-layer convolutional neural net converge to a smaller set of solution filters if the singular values are dissimilar?

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am experimenting with a 1 layer convolutional neural net and am seeing a pattern that I'd like some help explaining (this is personal interest, I am not a student).

I have picked a single 3x3 input matrix and an arbitrary 3x3 output matrix (that I know can be converged to using a single 2x2 filter with initial values between -1 and 1). I have a loop that generates lots of initial filters, for each one it collects the two singular values of the initial filter, trains the filter until it produces the output to 5 decimal places, and then stores the frobenius norm of the solution filter. The norm is intended to be a weak binning mechanism for separating different filter solutions since there are many (my instinct says there are a finite number of solutions for this experimental setup but I'm not sure how to disprove that so I don't know for sure).

I am plotting the singular values of the initial filter on the equal length axes while the short axis is the norm axis.

[image: Animated wide angle view]
[image: Frobenius view]

You can see in the pictures that there are few solutions when both singular values of the initial matrix are small. As the singular values increase in magnitude the number of solutions increases. There are fewer solutions when one of the singular values is small while the other is large. In the extreme case where one singular value is less than ~.5 and the other is greater than ~1.5 there seem to be three distinct regions of solutions that appear. This has been focused upon in the non-animated image.

I'm curious if these general features have an analytic explanation that doesn't stem from the particular input and output matrices I've chosen. I've reproduced the experiment with other source and target values and have seen similar results which makes me suspect that these features are not unique to the data I'm using.

My 3x3 source for the convolutional net is {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} and the 3x3 targets are generated by convolving a random 2x2 matrix against the source (the above images were generated by applying {.52, .53, .354, .255} to the source).

Any insights into why the solution region looks the way it does, especially why there appear to be 3 isolated solution regions when the singular values are <.5 and >1.5 would be greatly appreciated.